# dangerouslySetInnerHTML on NEXT JS

Tags: next.js, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I have a problem displaying this html string on next js. Here's what I did

```
const details = "<p>All confirmed bookings:</p><ul><li>Travelling up to&nbsp;<strong>31st August 2023</strong>&nbsp;will be charged the additional park fee at the property</li><li>Travelling between&nbsp;<strong>1st September 2023 - 15th October 2023</strong>&nbsp;will have the choice to be invoiced prior to travel or pay the additional park fee at the property</li><li>Travelling after&nbsp;<strong>15th October 2023</strong>&nbsp;onward will be invoiced</li></ul>"

return (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: details}} />
)
```

Sample image of how it was supposed to look like
[image]

Here's what I get
[image]

Even using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser results the same way. But when I inspect element I can see the HTML tags being rendered.
[image]

Comment: Nothing seems wrong here in your code kindly check if there are any CSS rules that might be interfering with the rendering of the HTML content. Ensure that there are no conflicting styles in their Next.js project that might be hiding or altering the appearance of the HTML elements